The overly large size of the dataset makes the GAMM curves sharp/angular?
I am currently building several similar GAMM models on numerous datasets with the same structure but varying sizes, with the smaller datasets containing about 15k rows and the largest around 400k. I’ve noticed that the larger the dataset, the sharper and more 'angular' the curves appear in the visualizations, and I'm wondering where my modeling error might be.
Here is the structure of my dataset and one of the autocorrelated GAMM models among those I've created:
glimpse(df.long)
Rows: 37,689
Columns: 37
$ word            <fct> ciepło, człowieczej, człowiek, człowiek, człowiek, człowiek, płaczu, słońce, właściwie, właśnie, wykłada…
$ C              <chr> "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w",…
$ V2             <fct> ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, a, ɔ, a, a, a, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, a, ɔ, a, a, a, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, a, ɔ, a, a, a,…
$ speaker        <fct> JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP, JP...
$ stress         <fct> unstressed, unstressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, unstressed, stressed…
$ F3             <dbl> 2018, 1883, 1870, 2082, 1982, 1866, 2109, 1933, 1839, 1891, 1923, 1683, 2011, 1929, 1872, 2008, 2013, 19…
$ time.i         <dbl> 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.5625, …
$ logdurz        <dbl[,1]> <matrix[43 x 1]>
$ period         <fct> 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1921-1940, 1…
$ period_num     <dbl> 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 19…
$ start.event    <lgl> TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALS…
$ C1bis.ord      <ord> labials, dentals, dentals, dentals, dentals, dentals, labials, dentals, labials, labials, velars, dental…
$ V2.ord         <ord> ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, a, ɔ, a, a, a, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, a, ɔ, a, a, a, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, ɔ, a, ɔ, a, a, a,…
$ stress.ord     <ord> unstressed, unstressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, stressed, unstressed, stressed…
$ V2.stress.ord  <ord> ɔ_unstressed, ɔ_unstressed, ɔ_stressed, ɔ_stressed, ɔ_stressed, ɔ_stressed, a_stressed, ɔ_stressed, a_un…

g.PS.CV.dur.AR <-  bam(F3 ~ V2.ord + C1bis.ord + stress.ord + 
                  #level 1 smooth terms
                     s(time.i, bs="cr", k=4) +
                     s(period_num, bs="cr", k=4) +
                     s(logdurz, bs="cr", k=4) +
                  #level 2 by terms
                     s(time.i, by=stress.ord, k=4) +
                     s(time.i, by=V2.ord, k=4) +
                     s(time.i, by=C1bis.ord, k=4) +
                     s(period_num, by=C1bis.ord, k=4) +
                     s(period_num, by=V2.ord, k=4) +
                     s(period_num, by=stress, k=4) +
                  #level 2: 2d smooth
                     ti(time.i, logdurz, k=c(4,4)) +
                     ti(time.i, period_num, k=c(4,4)) +
                  #level 3: 2d smooth by terms
                     ti(time.i, period_num, k=c(4,4), by=stress.ord) +
                     ti(time.i, period_num, k=c(4,4), by=V2.ord) +
                     ti(time.i, period_num, k=c(4,4), by=C1bis.ord) +
                  #random terms
                     s(time.i, speaker, bs="fs", m=1, k=4) +
                     s(mot, bs="re"), 
                   data = ds.w.CV.long,
                   method = "fREML",
                   nthreads=12,
                   rho=r1, AR.start = ds.w.CV.long$start.event,
                  gamma = 1.75,
                  select = TRUE)
saveRDS(g.PS.CV.dur.AR, "g.PS.CV.dur.AR")

And here is the basic syntax for my graphs (later refined in ggplot2; here, I’m just posting one of the base graphs)
c1_levels <- unique(ds.w.CV.long$C1bis.ord)
all.period.plots <- do.call(rbind, lapply(c1_levels, function(level) {
  temp_plot <- plot_smooth(g.PS.CV.dur.AR, view = "time.i", plot_all = "period_num", 
                           rm.ranef = FALSE, n.grid = 100, cond = list(C1bis.ord = level), return.plot = TRUE)$fv
  temp_plot$C1bis.ord <- level
  temp_plot
}))


What I’ve already tried to see what effect it might have on my curves: adjusting the values of k (I admit that I still struggle to choose sensible values here, so I tested models with varying numbers of knots in different configurations), adjusting the gamma value, from 1.1 to 1.9, and finally attempting to correct this at the graph level by testing different n.grid values, from 10 to 200.
Adjusting these parameters has no impact on this aspect, which remains rather counterintuitive; I would have expected smoother curves with more data. I’m wondering how to proceed to better understand this phenomenon.
Thank you very much for your help,
Jul

That's odd; even with such a low value,k=4, the smooth must, by definition given the order of the penalty used, be smooth. Usually, this issue happens when the underlying smooth is very wiggly and the number of points at which the smooth is evaluated for plotting is too low to achieve visual smoothness on the plot. But here you are using k=4 (so not very wiggly - you aren't really allowing for much variation beyond a cubic function here) and you are setting n.grid = 100 which should be more than sufficient. It's almost as if n.grid = 30 (the default) was being used?

Thank you for your remarks, I find it odd as well. The only regularity I see is the data size: this sharp effect on the curve disappears when I reduce the dataset. Besides, I really don’t want to remove terms from the model, as they were carefully chosen to represent a real effect; removing them would go against the assumptions of the experiment.

In case there was confusion, nothing I wrote should be interpreted as my telling you to remove terms from the model. Do you see the same behaviour if you use plot_smooth() directly (rather than inside an lapply() call)? Also, try vis.gam() from mgcv itself. I would always go back to the simplest possible case/code when faced with a problem like this.

I tested simpler models, and the issue lies in the term s(mot, bs="re"). If we remove this term, the curves are smooth, and there is no irregularity. In the version where I define this random term as s(time.i, speaker, bs="fs", m=1, k=4), the problem persists. How could we explain this irregularity?
